# Core Plot Title Alignment and Font Style

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is there any way an alignment can be provided for the title in Core Plot apart from setting the graph title displacement.I am having a dynamic graph title and hence the title displacement would also have to be adjusted accordingly for each case. Also is there a way to set the font Style of the title say make it Bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor` and `titleDisplacement` don't give enough control, you can always use a Core Plot layer annotation to position your own custom title anywhere you want.

Core Plot text styles include several properties including the font, size, color, bold, and italics. If you want the whole title to use one style, just set the `title` string and the `titleTextStyle`. If you want parts of the title to have different styles, use the `attributedTitle` (which takes an `NSAttributedString`) instead. See some of the plots in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.

Comment: Will go through the suggested examples. Thanks Eric.

Comment: Will NSMutableAttributeString work for the graph title?

Comment: For the `attributedTitle`, yes.

Comment: Any example in the Plot Gallery that demonstrates the use of attributedTitle ?

Comment: Not for the graph title, but you'll see attributed strings used for legend entries in the math function plot and the simple pie chart. You'll find `attributedTitle` examples in the Mac *CPTTestApp* for the graph and the axes.